# Disable GitHub Actions when forking cardano-node

Tags: cardano-node

Would you please give me a hint of where to look or modify? I don't even know if they have a charge associated.

If  you were to fork https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node.git, the GitHub Actions would continue running autonomously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

github actions are triggered by the contents of the `/.github` directory - specifically the `workflows` subdir.
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/tree/master/.github

See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/quickstart

You can delete or rename the directory to stop github actions.

Or disable them on your fork
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/disabling-and-enabling-a-workflow